# MIgrate Oracle DB data into Mysql db

Tags: mysql

There are multiple table in my Oracle DB that I plan to migrate into Mysql db.

The way I imagine is that
1.Go to each oracle table to execute some sort of cmd to generate the create statement that I can paste in my Mysql prompt.

However, due to my newbie knowledge in db, Does it really exist such simple cmd to do that?
If yes, can I even execute this idea batchly?